# Performance logs for latest Chromedriver not working

Tags: python, performance, selenium-webdriver, logging, selenium-chromedriver

I used to log the performance stats of my web scraper with:

```
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
# logs
d['goog:loggingPref'] = {'performance':'ALL'}
```

But after the latest updates I can't seem to make it work.

```
logs = driver.get_log('performance')
```

Now I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.198)
```

Did anything change in some recent updates about the way I need to initialize the performance logging in DesiredCapabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DesiredCapabilities which was earlier deprecated, is now removed in [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) [***v4.10***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22f).

---

### Solution

You have to use an instance of [ChromeOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
driver = Chrome(options=options)
```