# New version selenium desired_capabilities Deprecate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to use ChromeDriver Performance Log to monitor network traffic.

I'm looking for some usage like this:

```py
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

# enable performance log
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = {"performance","all"}
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    desired_capabilities=capabilities
)

# get performance log
logs = driver.get_log("performance")
```

Since my version of selenium 4.10.0

`desired_capabilities` property is Deprecated.

```py
webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opts)
```

This option is allowed but I could not use `desired_capabilities`。

I want to know how to setup `desired_capabilities` to Chrome or how to open Performance Log in order to trace traffic details.

Comment: desired_capabitlites parameter might have been merged into options as you mentioned. You might want to check [this change](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#after) and [this example](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#proxy), and [this one about performance metrics](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/#collect-performance-metrics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*`DesiredCapabilities`*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-98e9e290ede5d0c7ac9e7df5b49edf63f5df5fcc946b7736e4a6139e4cda26e3L30) earlier deprecated, is now completely removed in [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) [***v4.10***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22f).

---

### Solution

You have to use an instance of [ChromeOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) and the [`set_capability()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76683328/7429447) method as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
# other configurations
driver = Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```